# Powershell doesn't create Registry Key

Tags: windows, powershell

I'd like to change the Lockscreen over the Registry and a Powershell Script.

The Problem is that
`New-Item -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PersonalizationCSP`
doesn't work.
I can create the Key manually in the Registry. Is the command wrong?

EDIT: I don't get Errors using the command and I'm running this as an Administrator

Comment: And i tried using another Path but the problem is probalby the "CurrentVersion" Path

Comment: I can confirm that the command is working with the exact same path on Windows 10 and Windows PowerShell 5.1.

Comment: Now i get an Error that the key already exists, but i cant see the key in the registry. Also not after a restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running from a Windows Powershell (x86) prompt which is 32-bit. This means the key is created under the `WOW6432Node` key: `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PersonalizationCSP`

Make sure you use the 64-bit PowerShell version.